# Can't figure out a geometric statement

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

There's a very self-contained statement in the screenshot below from a book on conic sections. Note that KP and XS are orthogonal to KF. Think of S and P as a arbitrary points on their respective straight lines and P' is constructed as described. For the life of me I'm not seeing why SP'/SP = KP'/KP.

[image: diagram]

Comment: I don’t see how the angle bisection is relevant, given this limited information. We all know that the angle bisector divides the opposite side proportionally to the adjacent sudes, but this seems irrelevant here. I think you need to provide more details.

Comment: Yes, those were my thoughts aw well. I'm relieved to see that a pro such as yourself is also stumped - and in the same way as me!

Comment: Alternatively, are triangles $KSP$ and $KSF$ somehow similar?

Comment: It's the external angle bisector theorem, which is very similar to the internal angle bisector theorem. $KS$ is the external angle bisector of $PSP'$, so the ratio holds. $\quad$ The condition "KP and XS are orthogonal to KF" isn't necessary, in fact $X$ isn't involved at all.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem#Exterior_angle_bisectors

Comment: Ah, @Calvin. Thanks. Since I've never used this, it didn't even emerge in my memory banks. I'm sure my favorite geometric and vector-algebraic proofs will both work analogously. (Interestingly, my favorite geometric proof is not among the proofs listed on the wiki link.) You should post this as an answer. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin It's not clear to me that OP has "provided enough context" (whatever that means in this case), so I'm going to refrain from posting an answer so that I don't annoy the MSE-gods.

Comment: @Calvin What this site has degenerated to — both with do-my-homework abusers and with all-mighty guards among the “experienced” — turns my stomach. I got stuck, too. It’s a matter of recognizing a less well-known result which escaped us both. ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

From the comments:

This proof uses the [external angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem#Exterior_angle_bisectors).
We apply the theorem to the triangle $\triangle PSP'$, where $KS$ is the external bisector at vertex $S$.
The theorem implies that

$$ \frac{\lvert SP'\rvert}{\lvert SP\rvert}
= \frac{\lvert KP'\rvert}{\lvert KP\rvert}. $$